# Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve some problems related to Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation when I came across this question

> Use Gram Schmidt process to obtain an orthonormal set of vectors from the vectors (1,0,1),(0,1,1,),(1,-1,3)

My attempt:
I verified that the three vectors are linearly independent.
Let $$\vec u_1=(1,0,1)$$ 
$$\vec {u_2}=(0,1,1,)-\frac{(1,0,1)'(0,1,1)}{2}*(0,1,1)$$
$$\Rightarrow\vec u_2=(0,\frac12 ,\frac 12)$$
Straight away I can tell that the two vectors are not perpendicular. What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: You first need to normalize $\overline{u_1}$ so that its norm is 1.

Comment: $u_2 = v_1 - Proj_{v_2}v_1$. You have $u_2 = v_2 - Proj_{v_2}v_1$.

Comment: @Braindead ah got it. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put (assuming the usual Euclidean inner product)

$$\begin{align*}u_1:=&\frac{(1,0,1)}{||(1,0,1)||}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,0,1)\\
v_2:=&(0,1,1)-\langle\; (0,1,1)\,,\,u_1\;\rangle \,u_1=(0,1,1)-\frac12(1,0,1)=\left(-\frac12\,,\,1\,,\,\frac12\right)\\
u_2:=&\frac{v_2}{||v_2||}=\frac1{\sqrt{6}}(-1,2,1)\\{}\\
v_3:=&(1,-1,3)-\langle\;1,-1,3)\,,\,u_1\;\rangle \,u_1-\langle\;(1,-1,3)\,,\,u_2\;\rangle \,u_2\\
u_3:=&\frac{v_3}{||v_3||}\end{align*}$$

and etc.